# Communication between two Azure Container Apps Environments using Dapr

Tags: azure, microservices, dapr, azure-container-apps

I'm developing a PoC solution for migration from Docker-base App Services to Azure Container Apps. The app is geographically distributed. There are two kinds of app deployments: *regional* (multiple regions with the same bunch of microservices) and *shared* (single-region deployment with some shared stuff).

The *regional* deployments query *shared* deployment frequently over gRPC.

Each deployment will use its own Container Apps Environment (CAE) with a vnet. Vnets will be peered so that *regional* vnets can access the *shared* vnet.

I'd like to use Dapr with its sidecars for service discovery and service-to-service communication between CAEs but I couldn't find any docs on this topic.

Have you tried to do such a thing? Could you tell me how to configure Dapr in CAE for calling another CAE?

Comment: You can only use dapr within one environment, not across environments. You'll have to use the external endpoint of the apps to communicate between environments.